# Keeping a c array in memory, to be able to access it later with a pointer

Tags: objective-c, c

I want to have a ivar which is a pointer to the first element of a c array, but I want that ivar to be able to access the other elements in that c array.

```
@interface myClass : NSObject {
    int * _arrayElement;
} 
@end

@implementation myClass
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        int A[50];
        _arrayElement= &A;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Once this method ends the c array goes off the stack and I cant access the other elements by shifting the pointer (_arrayElements + 5 would give me A[5]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate the array on the heap, not on the stack. The arrays and other variables allocated on the stack are reclaimed by the system when they go out of scope, which means that you cannot refer to them outside of the function/block they are declared in, technically this is called undefined behaviour, and in practise usually causes your code to crash. Use `malloc`. So instead of:

```
int A[50];
_arrayElement = &A;
```

simply:

```
_arrayElement = (int*) malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
```

Remember to deallocate the memory with `free` when you are done with it:

```
free(_arrayElement);
```

Alternatively you can allocate and deallocate the memory C++ style, using `new` and `delete` keywords:

```
_arrayElement = new int[50];
```

and, to release the memory:

```
delete[] _arrayElement;
```

Note that if you choose to use `new` and `delete` you will have to compile you source as Objective-C++ code. To do it with Xcode it should be enough to change the extension of the file from `.m` to `.mm`.

Another thing is that if you are OK with using C++ constructs and libs then you can consider using `std::vector<int>` instead of `int *`;

Comment: Perhaps make it clear that you should assign that directly to the _arrayElement member (i.e. _arrayElement = A) rather than taking the address of it as in the original code.

Comment: Good point, I will change it. To be honest I didn't even read the rest of the code after I saw the local array.

Comment: Probably better to use `_arrayElement = new int[50];` (and delete with `delete [] _arrayElement;`)

Comment: @HotLicks wouldn't that assume Objective-C++ (which OP didn't specify and turning it on slows compilation down considerably)?   How would it be better than a simple `malloc()`?   Note also, that you can simply declare the instance variable as `int arrayElement[50];` as long as it is of fixed size at compile time.  This saves the need for an extra allocation.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will be better, but I can add it as an alternative.

Comment: @bburn Yes, that would require compiling the source as Objective-C++, `new` and `delete` are C++ things.